# downloaded images appears in recent files android

Tags: android, okhttp, android-download-manager

I am downloading some pics using OkHttp lib, everything is ok but all of them appears in recent files. Is there a way to disable my pics to be there.
     My code is:

```
public static void downloadSimpleFile(String urlLink, String myPath, String fileName) {
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(myPath + fileName));
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int read;

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setWriteTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlLink)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response != null) {

                InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception code treatement
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

like @Knossos mentioned in comments, I create this .nomedia file, but my pics still appearing, used code:

```
public static void createNoMediaFile() {
    File file = new File(mypath + ".nomedia");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                //is created
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is essentially the functionality of Android automatically adding your new files to the MediaStore. If you do not want new files in a directory being added, you *may* be able to firstly create a file in that directory called `.nomedia`. In which case, those images will not be checked. Such as: `new File(myPath, ".nomedia").createNewFile();`

Comment: Also you can try to use app private directory for storing images.